# Hide back button of navigation bar in Story board iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, back-button

I would like to hide back button of navigation bar which is a part of Story board, I have tried different following code snippets in detail view button nothing seems to work for me.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
```

PS: I am also having tab bar along with navigation bar in my story board

Comment: Not sure why this question has been voted down, if you guys have guts to provide the answer then mention the same, voting down this post doesn't answer my question

Comment: Which method are you calling this in?  If it is in `viewDidLoad` try moving it to `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 9):

Add this line in the viewDidLoad of your ViewController where you would like to hide the back bar button:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Tested successfully in a storyboard project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton= YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have added your own button to the navigationController and want to hide that as well (such as while editing text), its a two line process like this:

```
myViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
myViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the entire navigationbar as follows:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

then in your storyboard you can add a navigation bar to your view controller.

The result is what you want but maybe users will be confused as to why they can't go back...

Comment: a login view is the root view controller of my app and after successful login I am showing a Home view, and on home view I would like to hide back button

Comment: In that case I would actually suggest it might be better to load your home view as the root and immediately open a modal login view on top that goes away upon successful login.

Comment: Yeah Even I though about that, but I am not sure about this odd behavior as self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; used to work for me but it seems story board is an exception

Answer (score -1):

Its too late answer but may help others.
To hide back button you can do this :

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;
```

You can also try with :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;
```

This actually hides left BarButton and back button is on left side, too, unless you change programmatically.

Comment: hidden property is not available like you mentioned in first code.